# MySQL Increase View Count Query - Very Slow

Tags: php, mysql

I have a site that whenever a user views a content, total view count is getting increased by 1 *session-based*. I am observing the slow query logs for a while and interestingly this query seems very slow.

Here is the query I use;

```
UPDATE video_content SET views = views+1 WHERE id = 'XXX';
```

Sample log;

```
UPDATE video_content SET views = views+1 WHERE id = 'XXX';
# Time: 170123 16:49:35
# User@Host: XYXY_dbE56[XYXY_dbE56] @ localhost []
# Thread_id: 6297490  Schema: XYXY  QC_hit: No
# Query_time: 3.145292  Lock_time: 0.000045  Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 1
# Rows_affected: 1
SET timestamp=1485179375;
```

I am using MariaDB latest version running under CentOS. Everything is up to date and 200-400 user are online real time basis.

I have heavier queries than this which executes at the same time but they are fine. Is there any way to optimize this query?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It can be due to row contention when u have many concurrent update on a single row. There're many ways to tackle that, e.g.,

- Use faster in-memory db such as redis
- Use slotted schema like

  create table counter (
      id   int,
      count  int
  )

when u increment the view u can

```
update counter set count+1 where id = FLOOR(RAND()*100)
```

And u can sum the count of all row to obtain the final counter value.
Assuming u have 100 counter row pre-inserted already

Comment: i tried the count+1 method but it increase the number x2 every time , so instead of 10 become 11 it become 12 instead which is logically weird ! any idea why this is happen ?

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say base on information that you provided.

1. Try to get more information whats going on with query. This can be done with [EXPLAIN](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/explain/)

There are many reason why query is slow. This depends on the structure of table, memory for database, speed of disc (how many I/O for 1 sec), etc.

If more complex queries are executed, this might be issue with table structure. Solution might be create separate table just for counts.

You can as well use **[iostat](http://sebastien.godard.pagesperso-orange.fr/man_iostat.html)** to monitor CPU statistics and input/output statistics.

EDIT:
After while I realized that I could be more specific about table structure. There are one column indexes and multi column indexes. There might be a problem.